# GPU calculations in Windows 8 Apps - both for x86 and ARM

Tags: cuda, windows-runtime, gpu, windows-store-apps

I have a very calculations intenstive app which might be able to take advantage of the parallell abailities of the GPU. I've been looking at Cudafy for .NET but the options in the configuration doesn't includes win8 apps, but it has .net, linux, win phone, etc.

Does anyone have experience with using Cudafy or any other GPU calculator frameworks in a Win8 app. If I'm not targeting ARM and just go for x86 I assume I can get this working with Cudafy but I would like to include ARM devices as well...

So GPU calculations for win8 apps targeted for both x86 and ARM is what I'm looking for!

Comment: cudafy requires the CUDA driver, runtime and a CUDA compatible GPU if you want to run code on the GPU (as opposed to emulation on the host CPU). That means no ARM for certain.

Comment: Ok, so that means that if want to use this in my app then I need to build and upload one x86 version which can support this and one ARM version which doesn't support this. And it's probably the ARM devices which would require this the most due to lower spec CPU...

Comment: Are you using Nvidia's [CARMA devkit](http://www.nvidia.com/object/carma-devkit.html)? AFAIK that's currently the only way to obtain ARM compatible CUDA software (haven't tried myself though). You'll probably have to contact Nvidia directly for anything else.

Comment: I'd recommend [C++AMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx), which definitely works on all three target platforms (x86, amd64, arm).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I'm sorry, but I just don't see mentioned anywhere that ARM is supported. Perhaps you have used it yourself on ARM, but I only see reference to using it with x86.

Comment: Hilo (an SDK sample) includes some C++ AMP pieces and I have run it on an RT machine.

Answer (score 2):

There is an API for parallel programming using the GPU from Microsoft. It's [C++ AMP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/08/31/10345173.aspx). You need Visual Studio 2012 for that (earlier versions won't do). VS12 Express is free and has C++ AMP API. Basic tutorials and setups of projects are given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/08/30/learn-c-amp.aspx).